# angular - import 3D party library styles only for single component that uses them

Tags: angular, styles, encapsulation

I'm trying to build a component which displays a chart using chartist library.
I wonder if it possible to import 3D party library styles only for component that use it.

Here is component code:

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chartist from 'chartist';

@Component({
  selector: 'chartist',
  template: `
  <h1>Here is chratist chart:</h1>
  <div class="ct-chart" id="chart" ></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './chartist.component.scss']
})
export class ChartistComponent  implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() name: string;

  data: any = {
    labels: [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'Mai',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Oct',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ],
    series: [[542, 443, 320, 780, 553, 453, 326, 434, 568, 610, 756, 895]]
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const optionsEmailsSubscriptionChart = {
      axisX: {
        showGrid: true
      },
      low: 0,
      high: 1000,
      chartPadding: { top: 0, right: 5, bottom: 0, left: 0 }
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      const emailsSubscriptionChart = new Chartist.Bar(
        '#chart',
        this.data,
        optionsEmailsSubscriptionChart
      );
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

So far i tried(unsuccessfully) to import libray styles using 'import' statement inside chartist.component styles

```
// importing 3D library styles:
 @import '~chartist/dist/scss/chartist.scss';
```

For some reason the only way i managed to get styles applied on the component - is by importing them inside global 'styles.scss' file, of root level of application (which i'm trying to avoid).

here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartist-component-question?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchartist.component.ts) demonstration

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by css isolation/prefixing. 
I have forked your Stackblitz to show that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartist-component-question-e5c82q
Look at the styles.scss for the explanation.

You can do that in two ways:

1. Import the styles in the styles.scss an put a prefix in (see stackblitz).
2. If you do not want to import globally but just in your component then you have to do a hard coded prefixing of the chartist styles. That you can do by using less to compile the scss to a css and let it add a prefix infront of each class name. This is also necessary if you want to set scss variables in your code and do a prefixing.

Prefixing works like that: All classes get another additional classname. This class name is used in a container (e.g. a div) that is around your code.

Orignially you have a class like_

```
.testclass {
    //some settings here
}
```

and you use it like that:

```
<div>
    </div class="testclass">
     ....
    </div>
</div>
```

With prefixing you have that:

```
.prefix .testclass {
    //some settings here
}
```

and use it like that:

....

Comment: Thanks, but i still dont understand: why those styles cannot be imported inside styles of 'chartist' component? is it to do with encapsulation strategy?

Comment: Yes. It has to do with viewEncapsulation. You could also try to set viewEncapsulation for the component to 'none'.